# are css class names with dashes supported in Markaby

Tags: ruby, markaby

Any idea if I can use classes with dashes in Markaby?

Doing `div.label-center` in mab file results in this HTML:

`<div class="label -">&lt;center&gt;`

Bonus question - is Markaby dead or alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this you must send a message to class because `-` is an operator in Ruby. Write code that way:

```
div.send(:'label-center')
```